# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ given four different conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ in a Laurent series valid for the follwing annular domains.

$a)0\lt \vert z \rvert \lt 1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,b)1\le\lvert z \rvert\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,c)0\le \lvert z-1 \rvert \lt1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,d) 1\le \lvert z-1 \rvert$

Ok, so here are some things I know, There are singularities at $z_0=0$and $z_0=1$

a) is the unit circle, shaded inside.$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=\frac{1}{z}*\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{-1}{z}*\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{-1}{z}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty Z^n=\frac{-1}{z}[z^0+z^1+z^2...]=\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,f(z)=\frac{-1}{z}-1-z-z^2-...\,$ which converges for $0\lt \vert z\rvert \lt 1$

b)is the unit circle shaded outside the circle. $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$$=\frac{1}{z}*\frac{1}{z-1}$$=\frac{1}{z}*\frac{1}{z(1-1/z)}=\frac{1}{z^2}*\frac{1}{1-1/z}=\frac{1}{z^2}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{1}{z})^n=\frac{1}{z^2}[\frac{1}{z}^0+\frac{1}{z}^1+\frac{1}{z}^2+...]=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z^4}+...$

c)is a circle with r=1, shaded inside. Here, Im not so sure how to manipulate the function and have gotten stuck

d)is a cirlce with r=1, shaded outside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For (c)

$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)}= \frac1{z-1}\frac{1}{1+(z-1)}= \frac1{z-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(z-1)^{k}$$

For (d)

$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)}= \frac{\frac1{(z-1)^2}}{1+\frac1{z-1}}=\frac1{(z-1)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(z-1)^k}$$

Comment: ok, so i see how you did the plus one and minus one but how did you go from step 2 to step 3, for c? Maybe I need to freshen up on series, thats where I always get confused

Comment: Let $r = 1/(z-1)$. Then $1 / (1+ r) = \sum (-1)^kr^k$ for $|r|<1 \implies |z-1|> 1$

Comment: It's the sum of a geometric series, $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^k$.

Comment: Sorry above comment was for (d). Same thing for (c) except $r = (z-1)$ and the geometric series converges for $|z-1| < 1$